# Parent objects with physics

Tags: physics, parent

Hi I'm quite new to blender so I don't even know what the technique is called to google it or any of the right search terms.
I want to make an object like this, the centre ball as the controller and the other attached balls parented to its motion but they have physics and drag behind the centre balls movement.

[image]

I was thinking to use a hair particle system but i need the "hairs" (the child stalks) to be two objects so I can colour separately the stick and the ball. If i make them one object i can't give them separate materials. The sticks attached the centre ball need to be completely rigid and not bend like cables, I already looked into soft body cables but they don't get as rigid as i want.

i am looking into rigid body physics but I don't know how to get the results I want.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with **Physics** and **Rigid Body Simulation** following the settings on the screenshot bellow.

Create a *Master Ball* and the desired number of child balls to be affected by the *Master Ball* on the screenshot bellow they are named "**1**" through "**5**". Make all the balls **Rigid Bodies** of type **Active**. Lastly add a *Ground* **Plane** object with some loop cuts to test the simulation - make it **Rigid Body** of type **Passive**.
Keep note of the **Shape** types of the rigid bodies!

Create the same amount of **Empties** as the child balls and parent them to the *Master Ball*. Copy the physics settings as given (the same for each numbered ball although they can vary in size and settings). Give to each **Empty** a **Rigid Body Constraint** of type **Point** and select the two objects affected by it (always the **Master Ball** as **First** object and the corresponding numbered child object as **Second**, ie empty **e1** - Second -**1**, **e2** - Second -**2** etc.)

Here is the screenshot of the set up:

[image]

The simulations was done in Blender 3.6.5 and should looks something like this:

[image]

Try reproducing it by description first. If something doesn't work quite right you can download the example blend file below:

[image]

Adding sticks to the balls are not described but basically you can parent one side of a thin Cylinder to an Empty "**e**" and **Track To** *constraint* with **Target** the desired numbered ball.